# Webpage does not change after editing it

Tags: python, gunicorn

In my Virtualenv created a "Hello, World!" webapplication to test Gunicorn.

This is the code that I am using:

```
def app(environ, start_response):
    data = "Hello, World!\n"
    start_response("200 OK", [
        ("Content-Type", "text/plain"),
        ("Content-Length", str(len(data)))
    ])
    return iter([data])
```

When I visit (http://127.0.0.1:8000) it clearly outputs: "Hello, World!" as it should do. But once I change the data string to: `data = "This is an edit!"` and refresh the browser, it still displays: "Hello, World!". My conclusion; It looks like I have to restart Gunicorn each time after I changed something in my code, which is a real pain in the butt while working in a development environment.

Is there a way to fix this?

When I perform a cat command it displays the code correctly:

```
(web)sl@cker:~/Envs/web/myapp$ cat myapp.py
def app(environ, start_response):
    data = "This is an edit!"
    start_response("200 OK", [
        ("Content-Type", "text/plain"),
        ("Content-Length", str(len(data)))
    ])
    return iter([data])
```

I used this command to start the server: `gunicorn -w 4 myapp:app`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reload gunicorn because its still holding on to myapp.pyc which is no longer the same as myapp.py.

[See here](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ReloadingSourceCode) for how modwsgi does it, you might find your answer there.

Comment: It is unlikely that the way mod_wsgi does it will work for gunicorn. Check whether gunicorn has its own development mode instead.